# how to get ranking of columns for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table like this :

```
data        S1   S2   S3   S4     S5     S6 S7....
Date                                        
2009-12-31  0   0   4   nan -0  0   0   nan 0   -0
2010-12-31  -23 0   -273    -0  8   -16 -2  nan 0   -164
2011-12-30  2   0   -50 -0  -1  -16 -5  nan 5   -96
2012-12-31  2   1   235 -0  3   10  -2  nan 13  184
2013-12-31  -1  1   300 0   -1  -18 -14 nan 1   -152
2014-12-31  -8  1   140 0   1   8   -17 nan -0  442
2015-12-31  25  1   168 -0  3   1   -16 nan 1   -168
2016-12-30  -10 0   147 -0  3   4   -11 nan 0   -1,039
2017-12-29  6   1   52  0   -19 2   -37 nan -2  -566
2018-12-31  19  2   113 -0  -5  6   -16 -1  -2  2,404
2019-12-31  2   1   111 0   3   6   11  -12 3   319
2020-12-31  5   0   -64 0   -4  8   4   -1  2   2
```

and I would like to get for each date the top (lowest) 3 columns names ie :

```
Date                                        
2009-12-31  S1 S3 S10 (where S1 has the highest value in previous table, S2 the second...)
2010-12-31  S10 S12 S1 (where S10 has the highest value in previous table, S12 the second...)
2011-12-30  S6 S10 S12 
...
```

I tried :

```
rank_sdg = (table.rank(axis=1)<=3)
collecte_sdg.columns[rank_sdg]
```

but get an error message :

```
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to do:

```
df.astype(float).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.nlargest(3).index), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
              0    1   2
Date                    
2009-12-31   S3   S1  S2
2010-12-31   S5   S2  S4
2011-12-30   S9   S1  S2
2012-12-31   S3  S10  S9
2013-12-31   S3   S2  S9
2014-12-31  S10   S3  S6
2015-12-31   S3   S1  S5
2016-12-30   S3   S6  S5
2017-12-29   S3   S1  S6
2018-12-31   S3   S1  S6
2019-12-31  S10   S3  S7
2020-12-31   S6   S1  S7
```